# Error launching remote program

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I am new to `iPhone` application. i just started with `xcode`. My problem is: I have created an app using xcode & `phonegap`, it's running without any problem in simulator but when i try to test it on my iPad it throws an error.

```
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 6074.
```

i dont know why this happens. i have searched it on StackOverflow but its kind of confusing (as i am new in iPhone app.)

please help me where i goes wrong & how can i solve this?

Application also open. After the application launched completely, after few seconds I got this error. after that My Application get crashed.

One more thing.

if i delete my old application then it reinstall it but it throws same error. but if i open that installed application then it will be my updated application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying to debug your application using distribution provisioning profile. If you want to run your application in debug mode, you have to sign it with development provisioning profile and certificate (**both in build settings and in target**). If you are trying to create a distributable, sign it with distribution credentials and add Entitlements.plist (again both in build settings and target).

That’s because you put the get-task-allow = NO entitlement into ad-hoc builds, to stop your beta testers from being able to run the app in a debugger.

["Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1682/_index.html)